# Flutter Navigator.pop(context) returning a black screen

Tags: dart, flutter

My Flutter Project structure is like this

```
Main() //Run App with MaterialApp and Routes
L HomePage() //Default route (/), with BottomNavigation
  L MoviesPage() //Default BottomNavigation Index and shows a list of movies form TMDB 
    L DetailsPage()
  L SeriesPage()
  L SupportPage()
```

After clicking on any movie it navigates forward to the DetailsPage() but when I call Navigator.pop from DetailsPage() it should go back to the previous screen but it doesn't.

The Navigator.canPop(context) return false But the hardware back button works absolutely fine, so how do I fix it?

**main.dart**

```
class BerryMain extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Inferno(
        {
          '/': (context, argumets) => HomePage(),
          '/detailspage': (context, arguments) => DetailsPage(arguments),
        },
      ).home(context),
    );
  }
}
```

**homepage**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _childnav = [MoviesPage(), SeriesPage(), SupportPage()];

  void onTabPressed(...)

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('...'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _childnav[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabPressed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex, //this property defines current active tab
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.movie), title: Text('Movies')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.tv), title: Text('Series')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.help), title: Text('Help'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**MoviesPage**

```
//Inside ListView Builder
Virgil.pushNamed(context, '/detailspage', arguments: args);
```

**DetailsPage**

```
//Inside MaterialApp > Scaffold > SliverAppbar > BackButton
Navigator.pop(context)
```

I'm using [Virgil](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/virgil) but I don't think it is the problem.

Comment: what does `Navigator#canPop()` return?

Comment: @pskink it returns false

Comment: Tried to repro but couldn't based on the snippets you've provided. Maybe there is something in `MoviesPage` regarding context that is the issue.

Comment: This is what I did to try to repro: https://gist.github.com/jromero/b9b28abcec0d961d477c173186d95ee9

Comment: @JRomero have look at this repo: [gist.github.com/purplecandy/076071650dc233ffcadc934c13a0bf44](https://gist.github.com/purplecandy/076071650dc233ffcadc934c13a0bf44)

Comment: I've updated the gist to closer resemble your structure but still no luck reproducing it. Might be worth either setting breakpoints and inspecting the `Navigator` object or taking the gist I've created and build upon it until it stops working.

Comment: If you use `Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);` then when do `.pop()` it will become black screen. Use instead `Navigator.push(context, route);` It needs some navigation to go back where you came from. `PushReplacement` simply replaces the screen

Answer (score 135):

This can happen if your `MoviesPage` has another `MaterialApp` widget. Most of the time you want to use `Scaffold` as a top widget for a new page/screen, but if you accidentally use `MaterialApp` instead, nothing warns you.

What happens, is that `MaterialApp` creates a new `Navigator`, so if you switch from one page with `MaterialApp` to another, you now have two Navigators in the widget tree.

The call `Navigator.of(context)` looks for the **closest** Navigator, so it'll use the one, newly created in your `MoviesPage`. As the history of your route transitions is stored in a first Navigator, this one can't pop back – it has empty route history.

Hence, the black screen.

**Long story short, to fix this, just use `Scaffold` as a top widget instead of `MaterialApp` in all nested screens.**

Comment: %100 it is right. MaterialApp makes the app the lost routing.

Comment: I am using MaterialApp only in main.dart, then also I am facing a black screen, while using `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) { return VisitorsIN();}));`

Comment: there should be one and one Material app. thanks @divan

Comment: The tutorial on flutter.dev shows use of different scaffolds between the views: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

Comment: this should ACCEPTED answer

Comment: I wish this answer was accepted because all the other answers showed before this and I probably wasted an hour or so on those. This worked instantly but also gave me a real understanding of what was happening.

Comment: @divan getting same error black screen -            this is my code not needed Scaffold using safeARea -
  return SafeArea (
     child: WillPopScope(
      child: Stack(  ))  how to fix in this case.

Comment: As a troubleshooting tip for this black screen issue, it may help you to forcibly clear the storage and remove the app from emulators and reinstall it when testing fixes. That seemed to help me.

Comment: Not working! I have just one `MaterialApp`.

Answer (score 34):

I had similar issues while poping back views, the way I fixed was instead of `Navigator.of(context).pop();` I use `Navigator.of(context).maybePop();`.

No more black screens after that.

Comment: maybePop() will also fail you are showing alert dialog from first screen. it only checks if it can pop or not. it will always return yes and will pop one widget in case you are already showing alert dialog.

Comment: This is not solution for clearing navigation stack.

Comment: this doesn't work.

Answer (score 22):

Just add optionally param `rootNavigator: true`:
Sample:

```dart
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context);
```

Edit: In some cases, this solution may not resolve your issue. Please make sure that there is only one `MaterialApp` widget in your app for all Pages.

Comment: this ans is woking for me

Answer (score 14):

I resolve it using this code:

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/route');
```

Answer (score 14):

Workaround is  `SystemNavigator.pop();`  [refer from this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9577)

Comment: This will actually exit the app. Not something OP is looking for.

Comment: this closes the app completely.

Answer (score 9):

I also faced that problem and Still i was getting black screen after trying all of those previous answers.I do not have any idea about MaterialApp or Scafold reason because my application main.dart was only using MaterialApp, So Scafold solution did not work for me.Now what Solved for me.

*POP BACK CODE*

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context)
```

*CODE THAT **DID NOT** WORK*

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(context,CupertinoPageRoute(fullscreenDialog: false,builder: (context) => ChildClass())),
```

*CODE THAT **WORKED***

```
 Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChildClass())
```

Comment: `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context)`work for me.

Comment: Your code perfectly works for me and rescues me from wasting time. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had a very similar problem and my solution was to pass BuildContext **context** from the created StatelessWidget to a global variable and pop that context from the global variable. So...

```dart
var globalContext; // Declare global variable to store context from StatelessWidget

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    globalContext = context; // globalContext receives context from StetelessWidget.

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SecondScreenPage(title: 'SECOND SCREEN'),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreenPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondScreenPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _SecondScreenPageState createState() => _SecondScreenPageState();
}

class _SecondScreenPageState extends State<SecondScreenPage>() {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(globalContext), // POPPING globalContext
        )
      ),
  ...
}
```

Now I don't get a black screen and I'm at my first page as if I had clicked on Android's back button. =)

I don't know if that is a good practice. If anyone knows a way to do that "more correctly", please feel free to answer.

Comment: Like I said, it was not the same. It was similar. I had an issue with navigation pop and maybe my solution (for my case) could help the programmer to solve his.

Comment: Actually, I would like to thank you. Your solution helped me because I was getting the black screen as well. So thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad my solution helped you. :)

Answer (score 5):

Check your `Navigator.push` code

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Nextscreen()));
```

if you use `.pushReplacement` you cannot go back, it means you cannot use `Navigator.pop(context)`.

otherwise, if you used

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListScreen(),),);
```

Kindly use this to get rid of the problem.

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438917/navigator-pop-not-popping-latest-route-off/49439464#49439464) I figured it out a way.

You should pass the `MoviesPage` context to the `DetailsPage`. And that context should be called in `Navigator.pop(context);`

for Example:
**FIRST SCREEN**

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      final BuildContext context;

      FirstScreen(this.context);///here u have to call the build Context of FirstScreen

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            home: FirstScreenScreen(this.context));
      }
    }

    class FirstScreenScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      final BuildContext context;

      FirstScreenScreen(this.context);/// and here also.

      @override
      _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
    }

    class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreenScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
     body: Container(
            child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: (){

               navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);

            },
            child: new Text('Go to SecondPage'),
            ),
          ),
       );
     }
    }
```

**SECOND SCREEN**

```
 class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      final BuildContext context;

      SecondScreen(this.context);///here u have to call the build Context of FirstScreen

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            home: SecondScreenScreen(this.context));
      }
    }

    class SecondScreenScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      final BuildContext context;

      SecondScreenScreen(this.context);/// and here also.

      @override
      _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
    }

    class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreenScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
     body: Container(
            child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(widget.context);///this context is passed from firstScreen
            },
            child: new Text('Go Back'),
            ),
          ),
       );
     }
    }
```

**Pass Data & Return**
 
if you want pass data and return, add a constructor with parameter in SecondScreen and 
call setState in method Fisrtlike this:

```
 navigateAndDisplaySelection(
      BuildContext context) async {
    // Navigator.push returns a Future that will complete after we call
    // Navigator.pop on the Second Screen!
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => new SecondScreen(context)),
    );
    setState(() {
     /// the passed value data will change here, when you change in second screen
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Flutter App should have only 1 MaterialApp
Why???
It is a core component that give access to all other elements

Technically thinking Material App contains App Title and a Home Screen widget

Here is my implementation

```
void main() { 
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: 'First Flutter App',
  home: FirstActivity());
 }
}

class FirstActivity extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _FirstActivityState createState() {
   return _FirstActivityState();
   }
}

class _FirstActivityState extends State<FirstActivity> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('First Activity'),
      ),
      body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Move Forward'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondActivity()),
          );
        }),
        ),
       );
     }
  }

  class SecondActivity extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _SecondActivityState createState() {
   return _SecondActivityState();
   }
}

class _SecondActivityState extends State<SecondActivity> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Second Activity'),
      ),
      body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Move Back'),
        onPressed: () {              
           Navigator.pop(context);
        }),
        ),
       );
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in detail screen you are use MaterialApp as a main widget you need to just remove MaterialApp and diractly return Scaffold and maybe your problem will solve this is work for me.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
       body: Container(),
     ),
    );
  }
```

instead of

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: Container(),
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to get rid of black screen, you can also use below method with as many pop() you want

```
Navigator.of(context)..pop()..pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share my experience in this, as I had the same issue.

Basically, `pop` from **empty screen stack** is the major cause of this issue.

In my case, I was doing a periodic operation (reading some data from the camera) on scanner_screen (which was pushed to the stack by a button on my main_screen), when the camera finds a specific text, I call `pop`. The issue was that the camera was reading too fast, and thus I `pop`ped more than once, which means popping from an empty stack.

At first I though that popping is fast enough to call dispose on my scanner_screen to stop calling the periodic operation that keeps popping, but it was not. That is why I needed to make sure that periodic operation is stopped manually before popping from the screen stack.

I hope that may help somebody.

Comment: Thanks. I had this with mobile_scanner...........

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues when I used Navigator.pop() it shows a black screen
I used "maybePop()" method with "then" method and tested of the value if false then I pushed the rout to my Home screen. Like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).maybePop(context).then((value) {
                  if (value == false) {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Home(),
                        ));
                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried every answer but only this code solved the blank screen problem:

```
if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue like returning same screen return black screen

```
    void main() async {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GetMaterialApp(home: Todo());
      }
    }
    
    class Todo extends StatefulWidget {
      const Todo({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
    
      @override
      _TodoState createState() => _TodoState();
    }
    
    class _TodoState extends State<Todo> {
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
     body: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
            //print(controler.text);
            //Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Todo("viral")));
            //_sendDataBack(context);
            Get.to(()=>Test());
    
          },child: Text("submit"),),
        ) ;
    
      }
    }
    
    other class
    
    class Test extends StatefulWidget {
      const Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _TestState createState() => _TestState();
    }
    
    class _TestState extends State<Test> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
            Get.to(()=>MyApp());
    
          },child: Text("submit"),),
        ) ;
    
      }
    }
```

and then i check my code and realize that i am passing wrong class i have to return class that have my widget tree so replace Myapp() to Todo() like below and that fix my issue

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
        Get.to(()=>MyApp());

      },child: Text("submit"),),
    ) ;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be help others to avoid black screens. As it helps me.

```
 if(Navigator.canPop(context)){
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }else{
      SystemNavigator.pop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the first version of my code [Huy Nguyen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62188087/1125233) answer really helped me. After changing some base code and doing some state management, the fix stopped working.

Because it is my login screen and I don't need to return back to this page, I am removing all routes before. So my fix is basically to check if I can pop, if not just push to the route manually.

```
if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context);
} else {
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
      .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
}
```

Please consider, that you may not be able to return data to the main screen here. In this case I am managing the state as it's pointed out [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

1. Import page where you want to go.
2. Use Class of that `Page-Ex.Appointment`

```
Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> new Appointment() ),);

3. Remove Push name from Navigator
```

Answer (score -1):

This behaviour also appears when the `initialRoute` is removed, something that can happen if you navigate to your first child by using:

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed('...')
```

The solution is clearly simple tho, just use `pushNamed` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Before navigating to another screen use `Navigator.pop(context)`.

Example:

```
Navigator.pop(context),
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
MaterialPageRoute(uilder: (_) => GoogleMapScreenRemasterd()),
(Route<dynamic> route) => false),
```

Answer (score -1):

this work for me, i think it's the better solution.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Menu()));
          }),
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a common problem. These are just simple Issues. This happens when you push New screen and there also  `MaterialApp()` widget.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Navigator.pushNamed` instead of `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed`

Answer (score -1):

On my case I was navigating via `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/profile');` But when i change the navigation like this: **`Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profile');`** Nav back is work properly

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the navigator >>>

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        return detailspage();}));
```

or you could also try creating a class

```
class MyNav {
  static navigateTo({required BuildContext ctx, required String routeName}) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(ctx, routeName);
  }
}
```

and then try with route

```
MyNav.navigateTo(ctx: context, routeName: detailspage.routeName);
```

Also add routes:{ } in your main.dart file for this method to work.

Let me know if it works.