# Why tabbar widget Navigator.pop(context) return black screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm using the DefaultTabbarWidget and Alert package. Alert package has a default cancel button. Cancel button has Navigator.pop(context) method so I'm current page tab bar and pop method working going to the black screen.

I want to pop method doesn't back any page.
How to use a tab bar and navigator design. (Tab page set default page)

I'm trying this code but doesn't know what I want.

```dart
void main() => runApp(App());
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        '/tab': (context) => DefaultTabbar(),
        '/translate': (context) => TranslateScreen(),
        '/profile': (context) => ProfileScreen(),
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
class _TranslateScreenState extends State<TranslateScreen> {
 _buildShowDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
//like alert cancel code
    // Alert(
    //   context: context,
    //   title: "Türkçe",
    //   type: AlertType.none,
    //   buttons: DialoB,
    //   content: WordConvertStream(
    //     word: this._data,
    //     key: Key("DialogWord"),
    //   ),
    // ).show();
  }
}
```

I want .pop() alert dialog close but doesn't close alert.

[Home Screen](https://ibb.co/5YWQvRR)
[Back Screen](https://ibb.co/5YWQvRR)

Comment: Both images you posted have a black screen. So do you just want to close Alert ?

Comment: @Hosar yep. I want just close doesn't pop page.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, I don't see where are you triggering the alert dialog. But if you want just to close it, add the property **cancelable: true**, this will show a cancel button. You DON'T need to specify **Navigator.pop**

Comment: @Hosar https://ibb.co/B6nwnZ2 look at ss. Alert library default cancel button and have navigator.pop method or have "X" icon in the top right same method.
Even if not why tab page **Navigator.pop** return the black screen?

Comment: Maybe my answer in other question solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56008299/8429100

Answer (score 0):

You need BuildContext for push navigation to Navigators stack.

```
void _buildShowDialog() {
 showDialog(
   context: context,
   builder: (BuildContext context) {
     return AlertDialog(
       title: new Text("foo"),
       content: new Text("bar"),
       actions: <Widget>[
         new FlatButton(
           child: new Text("Close"),
           onPressed: () {
             Navigator.of(context).pop();
           },
         ),
       ],
     );
   },
 );
}
```