# How to navigate inside a form widget?

Tags: flutter

Now I am making an app where there is form and within it a button which when pressed should validate and navigate the user to some to the page below the stack but whenever I am using  `Navigator.pop(context)`
it screen is turning black or even if I use `Navigator.pushedName(context, *name of route*)`  it is showing null.

Why is this happening and is there a way to solve this.

**EDIT**

```
class Diary extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
         elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: DiaryForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DiaryForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DiaryFormState createState() => _DiaryFormState();
}

class _DiaryFormState extends State<DiaryForm> {

  final _diaryKey=GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String title;
  String diary;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final serviceViewModelProvider=Provider.of<ServiceViewModel>(context,listen:false);
    return Form(
      key: _diaryKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Title',
                  ),
                    maxLength: 50,
                    validator: (value){
                    if(value.length<=3){
                      return 'Title should be atleast three character long';
                    }
                     return null;
                    },
                    onChanged: (value){
                    setState(() {
                      title=value;
                    });

                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      maxLines: null,
                      maxLength: 800,
                      maxLengthEnforced: true,
                      minLines: 13,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Tell me what happened ...',
                        helperText: 'Try to follow in character length limit'
                      ),
                      validator: (value){
                        if(value.length<=20){
                          return 'Atleast write 20 words ';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState(() {
                          diary=value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),

                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child:Text('Validate'),
                  onPressed: (){
                    print(diary);
                    if(_diaryKey.currentState.validate()){
                      print('Validate');
                      serviceViewModelProvider.setData(title, diary, DateTime.now());
                      Navigator.pop(context);

                     // if(Provider.of<User>(context,listen: false) != null){print(Provider.of<User>(context,listen: false).uid);}

                      _diaryKey.currentState.reset();
                    }
                  },
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can see I have one button **arrow_back** and one button in the form widget but are meant to perform the same task of poping back to previous screen still.
While the latter button is not working and whenever I pressed it screen turns black and the former is working. And one more thing even if I am using `Navigator.pushedName`  it showing **there id no route with the this name.**

```
initialRoute: '/wrapper',
     routes: {
       '/wrapper':(context)=>Wrapper(),
       '/signIn' :(context)=>SignIn(),
       '/signUp' :(context)=>SignUp(),
       '/diary'  :(context)=>Diary(),
       '/home'   :(context)=>Home()
     },
```

This is the list of named routes in **main.dart**

Comment: Can so post your code so we have more idea of what's going on?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JideGuru,@nvoigt I have added the code please let me know how to proceed

Comment: Comment this code => `_diaryKey.currentState.reset();` and try **Use Navigator.pop(context) first**. Also, if you're trying to use, make sure you name it correct, `Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'your_router_name');`. I can see that you have named the method wrong. This might be the reason as well, make sure it is `pushNamed()`, not `pushedName()`.

Comment: No in code I have pushNamed, because it tell when there is a error so there is no chance that I could commit any error in spelling

Comment: Did you check the first thing which I told you to do, that is to comment this code `_diaryKey.currentState.reset();` and try with `Navigator.pop(context);`

Comment: yes it is not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723294/flutter-navigator-popcontext-returning-a-black-screen

Comment: It has the answer of above question

Answer (score 0):

@Ashu left in the comments a link for a related questions that also answers this.

But to leave it clear in here:

1. MaterialApp creates a Navigator object, so do not use 2 Material Apps, what you probably want is a Scaffold.
2. Scaffold is mandatory when using an MaterialApp, so accordingly to how someone is doing their screens it is like that they want to use it.
3. Pop actually removes your screen, so you should prevent it usage in the 1º page. A `WillPopScope` widget can be used for adding functionality like an Alert Dialog

Other may have other beneficial mentions regarding this. This were the one that came my mind. Hope it helps.